# What option define the using of `WcfSvcHost` in the `WCF Service Library` template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

WCF, .Net 4.6, Visual Studio 2015

From the *Programming WCF Services, 4th Edition* by Juval Lowy book:

> Visual Studio offers several WCF project templates. The WCF Service
>   Library project is merely the prebuilt usage of *WcfSvcHost* and
>   *WcfTestClient*. The main difference when using the WCF Service Library
>   template is that there is no need to specify the config file and
>   specify *WcfSvcHost.exe* as the startup program, because the project
>   file will contain a new `ProjectTypeGuids` element for a WCF service
>   library. The WCF Service Library also provides you with a simple
>   template for a service contract and its implementation, as well as the
>   matching config file.

But even if I comment the `ProjectTypeGuids` element in my `CSPROJ`-file then IDE still uses *WcfSvcHost* as *Start external program*... Hm...

By default the `Debug` tab of the new project is created on the base *WCF Service
Library* template has such settings:

[image]

I see the *Start external program* option is empty...

Why Visual Studio 2015 project still uses *WcfSvcHost* as *Start external program* even after I commented the `ProjectTypeGuids` element? What option define such behaviour?

Comment: What book are you referring to?

Comment: *Programming WCF Services, 4th Edition* by Juval Lowy.